# Unable to pass argument in invoke powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to pass value for argument in below command script called install.ps1. I execute it by ./install.ps1 HD1

```
invoke-command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {G:\usr\sap\$($args[0])\hdbclient\hdbuserstore.exe list}
```

but it gave an error to me that

> The term 'G:\usr\sap\$($args[0])\hdbclient\hdbuserstore.exe' is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
>   program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
>   verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (G:\usr\sap\$($a...dbuserstore.exe:String) [],
>   CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   + PSComputerName        : hostname

Comment: What `($args[0])` is supposed to contain? It is passed as string literal, not expanded variable, so the OS is looking for wrong path.

Comment: It supposed to accept HD1 value which I am passing as an argument with install.ps1.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the `-Argumentlist` parameter on `Invoke-Command`. Let me show an example below. Use the Param method inside the scriptblock if you want to use custom variable names.

```
$Directory = "HD1"
$Scriptblock = {
    param($Var1)
    G:\usr\sap\$Var1\hdbclient\hdbuserstore.exe list
}
invoke-command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock -ArgumentList $Directory
```